# Magento upgrading with Git

Tags: git, magento, merge, github, upgrade

I am about to upgrade our Magento store from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0, I know how I *want* to do it, but I'm a little unsure on the commands I needs to use.

For starters I have my current store on our production server, I have git setup and a duplicate of the repo is on our [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com) account. I have a full history of changes etc. within that repo and would ideally like to keep those in place.

I have a theme that we purchased and then quite heavily optimised but thankfully almost all optimisations are within an override.css file. Although, there are a few minor code changes within the theme files themselves.

As Magento use SVN as their CVS I have found (on Github) a mirror of Magento releases.

So, so far I have three locations that I would like to 'merge':

1. Production (git)
2. Magento mirror (git)
3. Theme (not git or svn, plain old directories)

I was thinking of adding the Magento mirror as a branch to my existing git repo, calling it 1.6.0 or similar. Then *somehow* pulling the plain theme directories and file into the master branch...

Am I on the right lines?

I was also thinking, to protect the production site, of adding a staging version of the website to run these merges on to test them.

Comment: Is your current branch based of the magento mirror from github? (I'm guessing it's the one I maintain)

Comment: @Lee No, I've never used your mirror on github before.

Comment: @Lee unfortunately your repo can't be merged without conflicts even with it's own branches so don't bet your $ on it.

Comment: @dannymcc [create your own magento git repo locally](http://blog.speedupmate.com/post/4063307705/magento-git-mirror) or use the [one](https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror) that merges down the stream without conflicts

Comment: @Anton If I either create my own git repo for the mirror, how would I then pull those changes into my current production repo?

Comment: @Anton Not sure what you are getting at about merge conflicts.  The mirror is simply that, a mirror of the Magento releases as they come out.  I personally use it as the base for the majority of the work I do and have never had a problem.

Comment: @dannymcc What mirror did you find on github then?  You mentioned one in your question

Comment: @Lee https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror

Comment: @Lee checkout your mirror and try to merge from first branch (branch by branch) to the latest and you'll see what i mean or let us say that you need to checkout some older version by tag to a new branch [example for you](http://pastie.org/2467213). The example could be just the scenario he has older version needs to be managed with git in the future

Comment: @Anton It works perfectly fine.  You just have to realize that Varien published 1.3.3.0 AFTER 1.4 was released, meaning the magento-1.3 branch has one commit that happened AFTER 1.4 and included some of the same code, like Centinel.  So, minus the 1.3.3.0 commit, you can do a merge using my mirror starting from 1.1 and going through 1.6.  I track each 1.x in it's own branch for that very reason.

Comment: @Lee You should include your logic to README or repo description for others to understand :) ver 1.3.2.2 - Added July 1, 2009 and ver 1.4.0.0 - Added February 12, 2010. My peasant logic tells me that versions should follow each other but that is not the case with your repo as you now explained and I never knew that so sorry for that then. I guess you should be able freely create branches from whatever tags you have in it by means of GIT

Comment: @Anton  I try to follow what Varien/Magento is doing with their code as much as possible.  The fact that 1.3.3 came out after 1.4.0 just to add Centinel support was a big pain.  If you look at the git branches in a tree view, it becomes apparent that 1.3.3 is not the parent branch for anything after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rather easy but you have to ensure that your site is based on some master repo that can be merged down the stream with earlier versions (repo that has all Magento versions as tags or branches that can be merged to latest from first). So here's two scenarios to follow

### 1. My site is not in git

1. start by cloning from master repo that has all magento versions (at least to the version you are currently using)
2. get your clone and checkout new branch with the version you are currently using
3. copy over your current site to this version
4. after that done "git status" will show you the diff with original version you started with and all the edits you have made to it
5. its now smart to move all core edits to local codepool and revert any changes in core to original files, move any edts in default or base templates to your own template and revert changes in default or base template files. Same goes with all the files that look modified against the original version. This gives you "all my changes are separate from original code and they will not conflict my upgrades", it's wise to commit this state
6. If all things are separated from original files then it's time to upgrade. Turn on default theme, disable all local and community extensions , merge the new version with your current branch. Visit the site to perform the upgrade
7. Now your site is upgraded and you can turn on your theme and custom extensions one by one to see what is compatible and what not. Debug and solve one by one

### My site is already in git

1. if it is based on repo that has all versions you are in good condition (skip 2)
2. if it's not then you can add some repo that has it all as your remote and start with merging your current version and separating changes from original like described in first scenario
3. make a new branch of your current site used
4. merge with new version
5. disable all local, community extensions, turn on default theme, and upgrade
6. enable theme, extensions one by one  and debug where conflicts happen

It's common to have a git setup like follows:

- MAGENTO MASTER -> REMOTE ORIGN THAT HAS ALL MAGENTO VERSIONS
- YOUR MASTER -> REMOTE ORIGIN IS MAGENTO MASTER

  - branch: yoursite_dev
  - branch: yoursite_stage
  - branch: yoursite_live

You always develop on your_dev branch andif changes are ready for evaluation you merge _stage with _dev and if changes are approved you merge the state to _live either from _dev or from _stage.

### commands based on theoretical endpoints

```
git clone git://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror.git yourprojectdir 
cd yourprojectdir
git fetch --tags
git tag
git checkout -b yoursite_dev magento-1.5.0.1
git checkout -b yoursite_stage yoursite_dev
git checkout -b yoursite_live yoursite_dev
git checkout yoursite_dev
git branch
//copy in your site
//separate changes or originals
//add any file/dir with local importance to .gitignore
//turn of your default theme, disable all local/community extensions and overrides
//assuming you are on dev branch commit your clean state 
git merge magento-1.6.0.0
//visit the site to execute the upgrade 
//enable your theme , extensions , debug
```

this gives you a starting point for scenario 1 and after that you could just copy in your site and start separating changes and making order in your current site and themes

Comment: ok so now I have my main production repo and I have added the magento-ce-mirror as a remote to it. Should I create a branch for the latest version and pull it from the mirror, or should I create a branch for my latest production state and pull the mirror into master?

Comment: added some pseudo commands to my post. note that if your original git repo does not originate from the master magento repo from start then you'll have separate trees and merging will result absurd change conflicts

Comment: Since he has the code in a git repo already and has history I assume he wants to keep, the best thing would be to look at rebasing his changes onto the branch based on the mirror.  That way he keeps his history AND gets the shared 1.5 history.  That will make the merge of the 1.6 code much easier.